# Unit tests - good practice when comparing object fields

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I am writing unit tests for my web application. I started to wonder if what I am writing is a good practice. I mean when an object creates a snapshot of its state and I compare the field values of the newly created object to determine whether they are correct.

```
  @Test
    public void testCreateUserSnapshotWithInitializedUser() {
        //given
        User user = aUser()
                .withUsername("Test")
                .withPassword("Pa$$word")
                .withEmail("example@example.com")
                .withRole(UserRole.COMMON)
                .buildInitialized();

        //when
        UserSnapshot snapshot = user.createSnapshot();

        //then
        assertEquals("Test", snapshot.getUsername());
        assertEquals("Pa$$word", snapshot.getPassword());
        assertEquals("example@example.com", snapshot.getEmail());
        assertEquals(UserRole.COMMON, snapshot.getRole());
        assertEquals(true, snapshot.isEnabled());
    }
```

Is the amount of assertion in the **then** section is too overwhelming? Or should I separate appropriate methods for each asseration e.g.

`assertUsernameIs("Test", snapshot);`

Or create one method like:
`assertSnapshotIsCorrect(snapshot);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna validate all the parameters, to reduce the number of assertions, you can map the object to String before asserting.

I usually made a class utils to do this mapping, like that:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class TestUtils {

    public static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static String mapToString(Object object) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    }
}
```

And then you can assert only once comparing the result and one previously build mock object:

```
@Test
void testCreateUserSnapshotWithInitializedUser() {
    UserSnapshot mock = UserSnapshotMocks.createUserSnapshot();

    var result = testCreateUserSnapshotWithInitializedUser(user);
    assertEquals(TestUtils.mapToString(mock), TestUtils.mapToString(result));
}
```

This way you will assert the entire object like one and only String.